# Cannot call `bindActionCreators` because `Action` [1] is incompatible with `ActionCreator`

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype, flow-typed

I have a React-Redux app and I'm using Flow for the types (I've followed the official guide [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/)). Everything works just fine but I keep getting this annoying error message that I can't figure out how to solve:

> Cannot call `bindActionCreators` because `Action` [1](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/) is incompatible with `ActionCreator`

The error is in `mapDispatchToProps` in the main component, App:

**App.js**

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import * as actions from '../actions/index'
import type { Action, Dispatch } from '../actions/index'
// ... more imports

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
    boundActionCreators: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  }
}

// ... mapStateToProps, class definition and so on
```

Then I have all my actions defined in actions/index like so:

**actions/index.js**

```
export type ToggleLoading = {
    type: "TOGGLE_LOADING",
    loading: boolean
}

function toggleLoading (loading: boolean): ToggleLoading {
  return { type: 'TOGGLE_LOADING', loading }
}

export type Action = ToggleLoading | ...

export type Dispatch = (action: Action | ThunkAction | PromiseAction | Array<Action>) => any
export type PromiseAction = Promise<Action>
export type ThunkAction = (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState) => any

export{
  toggleLoading
}
```

Have anyone any idea what is the cause of this error? Maybe just Flow?

Answer (score 0):

Simply return bindActionCreator in your mapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
```

I've read and use this blog post to setup Flow/React/Redux:

[type checking react redux](https://blog.callstack.io/type-checking-react-and-redux-thunk-with-flow-part-2-206ce5f6e705)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too today. It's a strange error because even though I had the same pattern on other files, I'm getting this error on only one of the files. What I did was switched from `node@6` to `node@8` and it fixed the error for me. However, I still find it strange why would I get the error only on a specific file and not the others which pretty much have the same code.